# Windows DNS server registers host internal IP, how do I change it to external one?

Tags: dns, windows-server

I have a Domain Controller and DNS server on Windows Server 2019 machine, hosted on AWS. I am trying to register a computer to that DC. The problem is, DNS resolution leads the computer into the internal IP address, which it cannot access.

DNS Resolution looks like that:

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Resolve-DnsName -Type SRV -Name _ldap._tcp.mydomain.com

Name                                     Type   TTL   Section    NameTarget                     Priority Weight Port
----                                     ----   ---   -------    ----------                     -------- ------ ----
_ldap._tcp.mydomain.com                  SRV    600   Answer     MYSERVER-AMZN.mydomain.com  0        100    389

Name       : MYSERVER-AMZN.mydomain.com
QueryType  : A
TTL        : 3600
Section    : Additional
IP4Address : x.x.x.x (Internal IP)

PS C:\Users\Administrator> Resolve-DnsName -Type A -Name MYSERVER-AMZN.mydomain.com

Name                                           Type   TTL   Section    IPAddress
----                                           ----   ---   -------    ---------
MYSERVER-AMZN.mydomain.com                     A      1200  Question   x.x.x.x
```

I tried to manually change the DNS entry, but it gets updated once a while. I tried disabling that updates with a Group Policy, but with no help. Rerouting the `_ldap._tcp.mydomain.com` entry messed things up and I had to revert it.

Is there any way to permanently register the external IP in the DNS server?

Comment: When you say"register a computer to that DC" are you implying that you are trying to join that computer to the domain that DC is responsible for?  If not, then why register a machine to a DC that is not responsible for that machine?

Comment: @Larryc I am trying to join the computer to the domain, yes.

Comment: can you tell us more about the topology, like why cant it reach the internal address? And more about the external address- is that assigned to an edge router or does the DC have a second network card? It would help to know more about how things are wired up.

Comment: You can certainly add the external ip to DNS but that doesn't mean you will be able to access it. If you could access it that way you would have to open numerous ports to allow joining a domain and that would not be smart for security reasons. Your best bet would be to gain access to the internal interface.